# Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch XXXXXXXXXX.diff

Tags: magento2, patches, composer

I'm installing a code base which is created by others, then i remove the old when i run "composer install" and encounter show many this kind of error message.

[image]

Anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try to execute

> composer install -vvv

this will give you more information. In our case the issue was "patch command not found", so we installed the patch and it works for us.

Comment: Any documentation for this `-vvv` param?

Comment: @NickRolando `-v` means verbose output for many Linux applications. `-vvv` just means triple verbose which outputs the most amount of information.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the time problem maybe OS does not have patch module install. So try this :

```
sudo yum install patch
```

can solve this problem sometime.

Comment: Thanks, this issue comes from the fact that some Linux distros do not come with preinstalled patch.

Comment: This could be a valid reason especially if you are using Linux flavors like Amazon Linux which does not ship with patch pre-installed.